# In TSQL, how to evaluate an expression and assign it to a BIT field?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling on something very simple. I'm trying to assign the results of a boolean expression to a `BIT` variable.

Basically I would like to do something like:

```
DECLARE @is_search_term_empty BIT

SET @is_search_term_empty = (@search_term = '')
```

where `@search_term` is a `NVARCHAR(128)` declared somewhere else in the code.

I cannot work out the syntax to evaluate something and assign it to a `BIT` variable, ie:

```
SET @is_search_term_empty = (1 > 2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
DECLARE @bitvar BIT 
DECLARE @search_term varchar(128)

set @search_term = 'abc'

SET @bitvar = CASE 
                 WHEN (@search_term = 'abc') THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
              END

select @bitvar
```

Comment: I thought for a second of using a CASE statement but I discarded soon believing that was a nasty hack! :P (Is it me or SQL syntax sometimes is so weird) Anyway, thanks for help! :-)

Comment: Would the downvoter to this old, accepted answer please leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

From SQL 2012 you can now use the IIf() function. Your example would now look like;

```
DECLARE @is_search_term_empty BIT = IIf(@search_term = '', 1, 0);
```

This is still essentially a CASE statement under the hood but is easier to digest.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set a **default value** for your **`bit`** variable then just apply a **`IF`** statement on it like this:

```
DECLARE @bitvar BIT = 0                    -- << Default value
DECLARE @search_term varchar(128)

set @search_term = 'abc'
IF (@search_term = 'abc') SET @bitvar = 1  -- << Value changes if required

select @bitvar
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons this is so hard to do is that T-SQL uses three-valued boolean logic. TRUE and FALSE are not the only options; there's also UNKNOWN. We have a similar concept with NULL values, and lots of language features exist to translate from values to boolean expressions (`=`, `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, etc.), but there's no such thing as `IS UNKNOWN`, or other language features to translate directly from a boolean expression to a bit datatype.

Here's an example solution. Unfortunately this requires that the expression you are testing (`1 = NULL`, here) needs to be duplicated in code -- you could avoid this with sp_executesql and output parameters if you really needed to:

```
DECLARE @bit1 bit = 0,
        @bit2 bit = 0,
        @result bit;

IF (1 = NULL) SET @bit1 = 1;
IF NOT(1 = NULL) SET @bit2 = 1;

IF @bit1 = @bit2 SET @result = NULL;
ELSE IF @bit1 = 1 SET @result = 1;
ELSE IF @bit2 = 1 SET @result = 0;

SELECT @result as [bit];
```

This example relies on the fact that NOT(UNKNOWN) returns UNKNOWN, not TRUE. This obviously relies on your BIT column being nullable. Similarly, if you wish to avoid three-valued boolean logic, you must ensure that none of your expression inputs can ever be null.